# common/web/js and css 404 not found while converting backend/web to admin and frontend/web to myproject/

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii2

In my Yii2 project,I have rewrite the URL from myproject/backend/web to myproject/admin and  from myproject/frontend/web to myproject/.

Frontend works fine but in backend the common/web/css/ and common/web/js/ is not loading and I this all these redirect to frontend and gives 404 page not found error.

I have checked the path of css and js and it's correct as below :
myproject/common/web/css/style.css. all css and js loaded with correct paths but it redirects to some other place.

I have used below code for rewriting :

I have added this .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

# End the processing, if a rewrite already occurred
RewriteRule ^(frontend|backend)/web/ - [L]

# Handle the case of backend, skip ([S=1]) the following rule, if current matched
RewriteRule ^admin(/(.*))?$ backend/web/$2 [S=1]

# handle the case of frontend
RewriteRule .* frontend/web/$0

# Uncomment the following, if you want speaking URL
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+/web)/.*$ $1/index.php
```

I have added this two lines in backend/config/main.php :

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'scriptUrl'=> ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost") ? '/chiefsRS/admin' : '/admin',
 'rules' => [
                'login'=>'site/login',
                'dashboard'=>'site/index',
            ]
 ],
  'request' => [
            'baseUrl'=>($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost") ? '/myproject/admin' : '/admin',        
               ],
```

I have added this two lines in frontend/config/main.php :

```
'request' => [
            'baseUrl'=> ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost") ? '/myproject' : '',

        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'scriptUrl'=>($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost") ? '/myproject' : '',
            'rules' => [
                'home'=>'site/index',
            ]
        ]
```

In my local server some css from common loaded and some gives 404 error.
In live server all css and js from common/web gives me 404 page not found error.
And error page has navbar of frontend so i think all css and js are redirecting to fronted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an issue with my .htaccess file. I changed my htaccess as follows :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(common)/ - [L]

# End the processing, if a rewrite already occurred
RewriteRule ^(frontend|backend)/web/ - [L]

# Handle the case of backend, skip ([S=1]) the following rule, if current matched
RewriteRule ^admin(/(.*))?$ backend/web/$2 [S=1]



# handle the case of frontend
RewriteRule .* frontend/web/$0

# Uncomment the following, if you want speaking URL
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+/web)/.*$ $1/index.php
```